# Exception in trend of increasing ionisation energy across a period

Tags: periodic-trends, periodic-table

One exception to the trend of increasing ionisation energy across a period in e.g. period 2 is going from N to O. There is no loss of exchange energy in I<sub>1</sub> of O, but there is 2K lost in I<sub>1</sub> of N, hence more energy is required to remove the valence electron of N.

If Z<sub>eff</sub> increases from N to O, and n stays constant, then

$$E=-R_H \frac{{Z_{eff}}^2}{n^2} $$
must become more negative, and I = -E, which implies that I increases, when in actual fact it decreases.

Is this equation therefore flawed?